# Default values for mandatory columns in SQLite (We're using SQLite Manager for Firefox). Are they necessary and if so, what should they be?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

My teammate made an SQLite database for our android app using SQLite Manager for Firefox but I noticed that most of the columns marked with an asterisk in the ERD do not have the constraint `not null` in the database he made. I asked him about it and he said he wasn't sure what to put for the default value. I've tried adding a column with a constraint myself. If I select `not null` but leave the default value blank I get this

```
SQLiteManager: ALTER TABLE "main"."productorder" ADD COLUMN "cart_id" INTEGER NOT NULL  [ Cannot add a NOT NULL column with default value NULL ]
```

I prefer that there isn't a default value for most of the columns but that the programmer is just prevented from making a row without giving a value.

We can give all mandatory columns default values if we have to. I found this question and it said that '' is acceptable as the default value for `VARCHAR` columns

[Laravel migration with sqllite 'Cannot add a NOT NULL column with default value NULL'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822159/laravel-migration-with-sqllite-cannot-add-a-not-null-column-with-default-value)

However I don't know what the default value should be for foreign keys (like cart_id), dates, zipcodes, etc.

Comment: well, of what use is a default zip code? "oh, this person signed up and didn't provide one. we'll just move them to 90210". defaults are useful in SOME cases, but you can't just go randomly slapping them onto everything. if the default value could be "wrong", then don't use an actual value. make the field nullable, and use null like it's supposed to be: "unknown value".

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking and why I said I prefer that there isn't a default value for most columns. But we want to make zipcode mandatory so we want to make it not null. Is it really possible to make something both not null and nullable? Or should everything be left as it is in the database and only enforce things being mandatory in the java code?