# Laravel test preserving records in SQLite while rolling back migrations?

Tags: laravel, sqlite, laravel-5, phpunit

I am working on a Laravel 5.2 app.  I am trying to set up testing using an SQLite in-memory database.

I'm aware of the SQLite problems related to changing columns that are `NOT NULL` without specifying a default, (for example [described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822159/laravel-migration-with-sqllite-cannot-add-a-not-null-column-with-default-value)).  An apparent workaround is to make the field first nullable, and then immediately undo that, in a separate transaction.  So I've spent many hours going over all my migrations and doing things like:

```
Schema::table('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('first', 128)->after('id')->nullable();
});
Schema::table('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('first', 128)->after('id')->nullable(false)->change();
});
```

I'm also aware of the SQLite problem where you can't drop more than 1 column per transaction (eg [described here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/sqlite-issue-dropping-columns-sqlitelaravel-providing-incorrect-errors)).  I spent many more hours updating my migrations to do that.

All migrations now successfully run and rollback without errors using SQLite and :memory:; they also run fine in MySQL.

So I added a test, using migrations.  The first and only thing the test does is use a Factory to create a customer:

```
<?php
namespace Tests\Unit;
use TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;

class PromoTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;

    /** @test */
    public function dummy_test() {
        factory('App\Customer')->create();
        print_r(\DB::select('select * from customers'));
    }
}
```

The output of the query right after creating the customer shows that it worked fine (fake data comes from Faker):

```
$ ./vendor/bin/phpunit --filter PromoTest
PHPUnit 4.8.24 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

EArray
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [email] => nRyan@example.net
            [zipcode] => 47049-6020
            [subscribe] => 0
            [created_at] => 2017-08-25 15:47:28
            [updated_at] => 2017-08-25 15:47:28
            [first] => Syble
            [last] => Hahn
            [phone] => (761)073-7794x8624
            [invalid_email] => 
        )
)
```

But immediately after that output, the test crashes and throws the following error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: customers.name (SQL: INSERT INTO customers (id, email, zipcode, subscribe, created_at, updated_at, name) SELECT id, email, zipcode, subscribe, created_at, updated_at, name FROM __temp__customers)

Notice the `name` field causing the problem does not appear in the created record above.  The `name` field did exist in this table in the past, but not any more - I removed it (with a migration) and now use `first` and `last`.  And clearly that migration worked, as the record created, inserted and dumped out above has the right, current fields.

So why is Laravel trying to insert records into an older version of the table, after it has already successfully created a record in the current one?

I am only guessing, but it looks like after the test is done, and the migrations are being rolled back, the data is being preserved and copied or re-inserted into each historical iteration of the schema?  There's no way that can work though ... ?

Has anyone seen this?  Is it expected or am I doing something wrong?

**UPDATE** The problem goes away if I simply switch to using MySQL for the tests.  Looks like I'll have to do that for now, as I'm stumped.  I'd much rather use SQLite in memory as it is faster.

Comment: Try to run your migrations into a `.sqlite` database and use SQLite Studio to inspect that database.

Comment: @IanRodrigues Thanks, I have tried that - the final schema after migration is correct, and there is no `customers.name` field.