# because the test doesn't work well, phpunit in laravel?

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I have the following settings:

config/database.php

specifically in :'connections'

```
'testing' => [
            'driver'            => 'mysql',
            'url'               => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host'              => env('TEST_DB_HOST'),
            'port'              => env('TEST_DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database'          => env('TEST_DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'          => env('TEST_DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'          => env('TEST_DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'           => 'utf8',
            'prefix'            => '',
            'prefix_indexes'    => true,
            'schema'            => 'public',
            'sslmode'           => 'prefer'
        ],
```

in .env

```
TEST_DB_CONECTION=testing
TEST_DB_HOST=mysql-db
TEST_DB_PORT=3306
TEST_DB_DATABASE=db_test
TEST_DB_USERNAME=root
TEST_DB_PASSWORD=secret_test
```

all my file `phpunit.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="true"
         stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>

        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
        <env name="MAIL_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
        <env name="DB_DATABASE" value="db_test"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

inside my test class

```
    use RefreshDatabase;
    protected $user;
    public function setUp() : void {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->user = factory(User::class)->create();
        $this->actingAs($this->user);
    }
    public function testCreateExcessCarriers(){
    var_dump("some text to try");
    }
```

and when executing:

```
docker-compose exec utraq vendor/bin/phpunit tests/Unit/Http/Controllers/ECControllerTest.php --filter testCreateExcessCarriers
```

**I get this error:**

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1
> Cannot add a NOT NULL column with default value NULL (SQL: alter table
> "users" add column "agency_id" integer not null)

in this way I have configured the factory, checking with the model everything is fine

```
$factory->define(App\Models\User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    static $password;

    return [
        'uuid' => $faker->uuid,
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'password' => $password ?: $password = bcrypt('secret'),

        'active' => 1,
        'agency_id' => 3,
    ];
});
```

However I don't know why I get that error after executing the command. How can I correct it?

**EDIT:**
Migration where I guess I get the error. For the Users table, there are 2 migrations.

Migration 1:

```
 Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('uuid');
                $table->string('name');
                $table->string('email')->unique();
                $table->string('password');
                $table->string('address1')->nullable(); //Address 1
                $table->string('address2')->nullable(); //Address 2
                $table->string('city')->nullable(); //City
                $table->string('state_name')->nullable(); //State
                $table->integer('state_id')->nullable(); //State
                $table->string('zip_code', 10)->nullable(); //Zip Code    
                $table->string('employee_type')->nullable();
                $table->dateTime('last_logged_in')->nullable();
                $table->json('dashboard')->nullable();
                $table->rememberToken();
                $table->timestamps();
            });
```

Migration 2: As you can see, this is where the `agency_id` field is assigned

```
 Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->integer('agency_id')->after('password');
                $table->boolean('active')->after('remember_token')->default('0');
                $table->boolean('verified')->after('active')->default(false);
                $table->string('avatar')->nullable();
            });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel migration with SQLite 'Cannot add a NOT NULL column with default value NULL'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822159/laravel-migration-with-sqlite-cannot-add-a-not-null-column-with-default-value-n)

Comment: I don't know how to apply it to my case.

Comment: Can you add the migration file where `agency_id` is located ?

Comment: I just added it.

Comment: `<env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>` it seems like you actually want to use your testing  connection right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question i suppose you actually want to use your mysql testing database you defined as "testing" connection.

But in your phpunint config you use

```xml
<env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
<env name="DB_DATABASE" value="db_test"/>
```

Which clearly relates to a sqlite connection. Others already pointed out issues with sqlite and adding not nullable columns

You probably want to change your connection to and remove the DB_DATABASE entry

```xml
<env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="testing"/>
```

EDIT:

`TEST_DB_CONECTION=testing`

Does not seem to be used anywhere? Also there is a typo :) - can probably removed from your env aswell

Comment: I have run the test again but now you get this other error from another table:
`Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table 'endorsements_requests' add constraint 'endorsements_requests_iquote_id_foreign' foreign key ('iquote_id') references 'iquote' ('id') on delete cascade)`

Comment: seems like you have troubles with your migrations - you will need to add the relevant migrations to your question if you want us to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this answer; https://stackoverflow.com/a/33416155/8068675

> It seems SQLite simply leaves you in a bad state if you need to add a non-nullable column to an existing table, which column should also not have a default value

In short to fix the issue you have 3 possibilities;

- Use the same DB **engine** that you use in production to run your tests. It's slower, but you are sure to see the same issues if there is any.
- Change to nullable: `$table->integer('agency_id')->nullable()->after('password');`
- (I would absolutely **not** recommend since it's a foreign key) Add a default value: `$table->integer('agency_id')->default(1)->after('password');`

Answer (score 0):

From my experience this boils down to a limitation in sqlite not being able to add a non-nullable column to an existing table without a default value.

The work-around we use is to split the migration into 2 steps within the same migration. The first step adds the column as nullable & the next step updates it to be non-nullable.

So your migration would look something like this (untested):

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('agency_id')->nullable()->after('password');
});
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('agency_id')->nullable(false)->change();
});
```

This is in principle what we use but might not work in all use cases. You might want to set a default value in the first step instead of making it nullable, if that suites your use case better.

*If I remember correctly the false argument in `nullable(false)` only became available later in Laravel 5.x so this might not work depending on the version of Laravel you are working with.*